# warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[22] Error: the heartbeat has been running for "00:00:03.3020278" which is longer than "00:00:01"

Tags: asp.net-core, threadpool, kestrel-http-server

I have a straightforward ASP.NET Core web app without any parallel processes. The functionality is to call the API, get the data and show them on Razor Pages. And I reload the page every after 10 minutes. This Service is running in the docker Linux container. If I check the container logs, they have so many warnings as below happening in between.

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[22]  As of "05/29/2023 04:22:14 +00:00", the heartbeat has been running for "00:00:03.3020278" which is longer than "00:00:01". This could be caused by thread pool starvation.
```

There is no background service or complicated loop code which can cause the thread pool issue.

**CPU usage of this Linux container is 1%.**
Please help me with what other reasons are possible to cause this.

**Edit:**

I diagnosed the APP performance using `dotnet-counters` , running the command:

```
dotnet-counters monitor --process-id 69860  --refresh-interval 3 --counters System.Runtime
```

It returns CPU Usage: 0-1% only

Comment: Do you have any metrics for this service? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters

Comment: No not using any metrics.

Comment: Its the first step in trying to better understand the health of the application. It'll give you more information (thread pool usage etc).

Comment: My project is asp .net core 6, I am trying to install the Nuget package dotnet-counters, but it shows an error that it is not compatible with my project.

Comment: According my experience, it should be the code issue, please check [the blogs](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/profiling-a-net-app-with-dotnet-cli-diagnostic-tools/), and using tools to check the issue.

Comment: I checked the metrics for this service, and the usage of the CPU is very low.

Comment: If you've already checked the counters using dotnet counters, can you update the issue with the .NET counters? There might be clues in there that help answer the question.